# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material-ui in react with typescript template. All of my code is working fine but I am getting this error on multiple lines (not an error warning but with red line as my code renders)

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'. 'C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Web current Projects/typescript/card/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'react' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react`ts(7016)
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10109) issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per @NearHuscarl's comment, a quick fix is to create your own declaration module for `react/jsx-runtime`. You can do this by opening the `react-app-env.d.ts` file (created by default when you use create-react-app), found in your project's root directory. Then add the following script to it:

```js
declare module "react/jsx-runtime" {
    export default any;
  }
```

The create-react-app team don't believe this is an issue for create-react-app to solve, and suggest it's a problem with typescript version 4. So alternatively you can downgrade your typescript version until the typescript team provide a fix in a later version.

Answer (score 34):

## Try restarting vscode and see if it got fixed

Comment: My issue does not happen inside vscode. What now?

Answer (score 6):

When you have this error, it is usually because you installed a library and you didn't install the types of that library.

To fix this error, you need to install `@types/library-name` using your package manager (npm or yarn).

Answer (score 3):

Came across this when trying to use create-react-app with typescript.

What solved it for me was changing the following file:

`react-app-env.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />

declare module 'react/jsx-runtime' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused by a version mismatch between the `react`/`react-dom` and `@types/react`/`@types/react-dom` packages.

Answer (score -5):

use yarn for manage package.

run this command

> yarn install